# How should I log External Web Services called from X++

Tags: web-services, axapta, dynamics-ax-2012, x++, aif

I’ve followed the standard tutorials to create an external web service reference.  My calls contain transactional data and logging is imperative.  I’d like to know what sort of logging I should employ when making these external calls.  I’d really love to have these calls appear in-line with standard AIF document history & exceptions, but I don’t think that’s easily feasible.  I also can’t find the SOAP request and response generated by my external service reference, making the logging even trickier.  I’ve thought about creating a custom outbound adapter, but I’m not sure if that’s the right approach. Just want to see what the professionals recommend.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/hh500185.aspx

http://daxmusings.codecrib.com/2011/10/consuming-external-webservices-in-ax.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way that we've found so far is to create a logging table in AX.  Saving serialized requests, responses, URLs and errors right into AX.  We've included other descriptors as well so it's useful anywhere external web services are called.  Provide a form for your front end, and consider a batch job to purge old records.

Answer (score 0):

Configure [Logging](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202045.aspx) at the AIF Port Configuration. Enable `All document versions` or `Original document`.
[image: AIF Logging - Troubleshooting]

Comment: Note: Depending on how much traffic there is. Storing the XMLs in the database can take up huge amounts of space. So clean the history up in time.

Comment: The question is about logging calls to external web services, not inbound ports.